# Bitcoin Core v.0.14. doesn't recognise recipient address starting bc1

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet, address

I have some problem with sending Bitcoin from Bitcoin Core v.0.14. When entering the address in recipient field it becomes red. And I noticed that the address to which the translation needs to be made does not correspond to my. My address contains digits, small and bit letters and address that i need to send contains digits and small letters only and it it has a more length. First 4 characters are "bc1q".  Can you help me in resolving this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What are the first 4 characters of the address you're trying to send to?

Comment: First 4 characters are "bc1q"

Comment: In that case you're just using a way too old version of Bitcoin Core. This is a BIP173 address (using Bech32 encoding). Support was added in Bitcoin Core 0.16 (released in 2018). I would encourage you to update to the latest version (0.21.1 currently), and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you for such fast response. Can I immediately set the latest version or is better alternately, starting from 0.16, and then 0.21.1

Comment: You can just update to the last version immediately. Make a backup of your wallet.dat file in case something goes wrong, but that's unlikely. There are several questions about details on this site.

Answer (score 3):

As Pieter Wuille explained:

An address starting `bc1` is a BIP173 address (using Bech32 encoding). Support was added in Bitcoin Core 0.16 (released in 2018).

You can just update to the latest version immediately (currently 0.21.1). Make a backup of your wallet.dat file in case something goes wrong, but that's unlikely.

<sup>(community wiki answer to remove this question from list of unanswered questions)</sup>